# Replacing console.log with document.getElementById("ID") for loops

Tags: javascript

```js
// program to display text 10 times
const n = 10;

// looping from i = 1 to 10
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    console.log(`I love JavaScript.`);
}
```

I try to replace `console.log` with `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I love JavaScript"`, but can't replicate the example.

Comment: What is `"demo"`? And are you aware that `.innerHTML = "something"` replaces the previous value? And what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: demo is basically just <p id="demo"></p>.

Comment: Alright, can you explain what you are trying to do to this `<p>` exactly?

Comment: I do not want to use console.log to produce the printing of "I love JavaScript" 10 times. I want to replace it with something like innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  `+= "I love JavaScript."`

Comment: yup this does the trick, thanks!. Is it possible to get the "I love JavaScript" flash 5 times, like a generator?